# Split cURL header info into array

Tags: php, curl

Consider the following PHP cURL command:

```
$url = 'http://bit.ly/faV1vd';

$_h = curl_init();
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );

$return = curl_exec($_h);
```

This returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 12:48:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _bit=4f9d3887-00215-020af-2f1cf10a;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Fri Oct 26 12:48:07 2012;path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-control: private; max-age=90
Location: http://www.macroaxis.com/invest/market/VZ--Sat-Feb-26-06-16-35-CST-2011?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 209
```

I want to split the header info into an array, as follows

```
[Status] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved,
[Server] => nginx,
[Date] => Sun, 29 Apr 2012 12:48:07 GMT,
...
[Content-Length] => 209
```

So:
 - the first line (HTTP/1.1 301 Moved) should be the value of [Status]
 - all other header info should be split on `:`

I'm not succeeding in splitting the header info:

```
explode("\r\n\r\n", $return);
explode("\r\n", $return);
```

This doesn't split the header into an array (to further split on `:`, etc. as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to split your header into an array

```
$myarray = array();
$data = explode("\n",$return);

$myarray['status'] = $data[0];

array_shift($data);

foreach($data as $part){
     $middle = explode(":",$part);
     $myarray[trim($middle[0])] = trim($middle[1]);
}

print_r($myarray);
```

As well as use  `curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);` 
if you need to return only header.

More info can be found here

http://altafphp.blogspot.com/2012/04/get-http-headers-of-any-site-using-curl.html

Answer (score 7):

The answer by [Altaf Hussain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372461/2889735) is good but does not support a case where the header response contains a `':'`. i.e. `X-URL: http://something.com`. In this case the `$myarray` will only contain `('X-URL' => 'http')`

This can be fixed by adding the [`limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) parameter and setting it to `2`. In addition, there should be a space after the colon. So the full solution with the bug fix is:

```
$myarray=array();
$data=explode("\n",$return);

$myarray['status']=$data[0];

array_shift($data);

foreach($data as $part){
$middle=explode(": ",$part,2);
$myarray[trim($middle[0])] = trim($middle[1]);
}

print_r($myarray);
```

Comment: Good! But you could replace `... = $data[0]; array_shift($data);` with `... = array_shift($data);`. This because [array_shift returns the removed value](http://www.php.net/array_shift).

Comment: Perhaps a neater solution: `$data = explode("\n", 'Status: ' . $return);` then remove the next two lines.

Answer (score 2):

cURL already supports a callback function for parsing the headers.

> CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION : A callback accepting two parameters. The first is the cURL resource,
>   the second is a string with the header data to be written. The header
>   data must be written by this callback. Return the number of bytes
>   written.

```
function handle_headers($curl, $header_line) 
{
    list($name, $value) = explode(": ", $header_line, 2);
    //do something with name/value...
    return strlen($header_line);
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "handle_headers");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just split it into **maximum of 2**

```
explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
```

and remember to setup followlocation and max redirect if you want the actual url to fetch

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```